# Wrapping a function in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

This code works to upload an image file:

```
var middle = multer({ storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'upl')
    }
}) })

app.post('/', middle.single('upload'), function (req, res) {
  res.end(res.render('index'))
})
```

The variable middle sets up the file destination and file name of the uploaded image file. However, I would like to have variables for file destination and file name that I can pass in during the function call so I wrapped it like this:

```
var middle = function (fileName, fileDest) {
  multer({ storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, fileDest)
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, fileName)
      }
  }) })
}

app.post('/', middle('upu', './uploads').single('upload'), function (req, res) {
  res.end(res.render('index'))
})
```

This second set of code returns undefined and I'm not sure how I should call the function or format it correctly.

Comment: Your `middle` function doesn't return anything

Comment: Thank you, adding a return statement works. The code however, looks terrible- is there a proper way to format this or a structure that I should be using?